# Overriding save in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, save, overriding

Hello i want to override save method in ruby but while doing so i get 
following error while saving a object with some changes

```
    User.name = "alex"
    User.save
```

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

My code is as below

```
class ActiveRecord::Base

  def save()
      p "in My save\n"
      Multidb.use(:default) do
          p "calling super\n"
      super()
      end
      p "saved\n"
  end

end
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by overriding `save`? Maybe there's a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is a terrible idea to override such an important method of the public `ActiveRecord` API.

But if you really want to override `save` then you should allow your `save` method to receive the same arguments as the [original `save` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) and pass these arguments to `super` too.

```
def save(*args)
  # ...
  Multidb.use(:default) do
    super(*args)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: You can just write `super` to pass any given arguments.

Comment: _"I think it is a terrible idea"_ – do you have a better suggestion for the OP?

Comment: I decided against just writing `super` to make it clearer what needs to happen. Better suggestion? Depends on what the OP really want to achieve. I would probably just create a method with a name that makes it easier to understand how this implementation differs from the original `save` method - `save_into_default_db`?

Comment: That approach would work if the OP wants to have both, the original `save` and a variant that uses the `:default` database config. If however the goal is to make the `User` model use the `:default` config, then having a different method name would probably not work well (think of `create` or `update` which still call `save` under the hood).

Comment: what I want to achieve is basically use default/master db only for write queries and for reading purposes it should go to slave db (which I set default in EB environment)